# Regex from a to z

Tags: javascript

Will this Regex syntax check for the 1st letter starting from a range of "a to z"?

```
(/^[a-zA-Z].*/i.test(mystring))
```

Comment: Write a Unit-Test and make sure.

Comment: http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ is your friend :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and you don't really even need the ".*".

Comment: Thanks for your response Pointy!

Answer (score 5):

Yes. It can be further simplified to `/^[a-z]/i`.

Breakdown:

- `^` = start of the string
- `[a-z]` = any letter in the range from a to z
- the `i` at the end = case isensitive, means that `[a-z]` will also match in the range of A to Z.

For more info, [check out this quickstart guide](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html).

Comment: Good point!  I was checking to see if there might be something like "\w" for just alphabetics; the JavaScript regex code is pretty bad about non-Latin characters that should be considered "letters".

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the ".*" because ".*" essentially says match every character(.), zero or more times(*). Since you only want to match one character, all you need is the ^[a-zA-Z], which makes sure the first letter is a-zA-Z.

Also to simplify this regex to:

```
/^[a-z]/i
```

because this makes the regex case in-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for your response Mike!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it surely  will do that and **/^[a-z]/i** would do it too

Comment: Thanks for your response Gl8!